# How to work with a nested function in redux action unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to learn unit testing for testing our react application. I'm starting with actions.

I have a function, the object that returned also has a nested function.

hello.actions.js

```
export function loadData(request){
    return {
        type: types.TEST_API,
        coreApi: {
            body: request,
            success: (response) => [receiveData(response), update(response)]
        }
    }
}

export function receiveData(request){...}
export function update(request){...}
```

What I tried to do on returning success, it'll be `() => jest.fn()`

helloActions.test.js

```
describe("Action: hello", () => {

       const payload = {
           request: "request"
       }

       const expectedAction = {
           type: types.TEST_API,
           coreApi: {
               body: request,
               success: () => jest.fn()
           } 
       }


       expect(actions.loadData(payload.request)).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
});
```

If I remove the success line from both test and action, it works. So I've pin pointed it to be something wrong with the success line. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I even tried to push `success: (response) => [receiveData(response), update(response)]` in the unit test but that fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expect().toEqual()` method can't compare two functions. See this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60989588/6463558)

You can use [expect.any(constructor)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanyconstructor) matches anything that was created with the given constructor.

E.g.

`hello.actions.js`:

```js
export const types = {
  TEST_API: 'TEST_API',
};
export function loadData(request) {
  return {
    type: types.TEST_API,
    coreApi: {
      body: request,
      success: (response) => [receiveData(response), update(response)],
    },
  };
}

export function receiveData(request) {}
export function update(request) {}
```

`hello.actions.test.js`:

```js
import { loadData, types } from './hello.actions';

describe('67236356', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const payload = {
      request: 'request',
    };

    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.TEST_API,
      coreApi: {
        body: payload.request,
        success: expect.any(Function),
      },
    };

    expect(loadData(payload.request)).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
PASS  examples/67236356/hello.actions.test.js (9.468 s)
  67236356
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |   83.33 |      100 |      25 |   83.33 |                   
 hello.actions.js |   83.33 |      100 |      25 |   83.33 | 9                 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.811 s
```

Comment: thank you for the informative response. This does allow for unit test to pass. I was wondering if it can be enhanced in anyway? Unfortunately unit test coverages `flags` success as uncovered  when set to expect.any(Function)